# Animating scene data using Webgl

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl

What is the best way to animate an array of scene data, with each scene (a decoded base64 string) one frame of the animation, using Webgl?

Comment: What are you animating? What's in the decoded string?

Comment: Hi David, I'm animating a series of surfaces, so each string represents one such surface.